# How to explode comma separated arrays from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am unable to explode comma separated data array from the database in codeigniter framework. I want to echo the array into multiple rows with string value like:

```
---------------
Product Name
---------------
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3
```

---

But i am getting array to string conversion error.

```
<?php foreach ($res as $key => $value) { ?>
         <tr class="border-bottom">
                <td>
                    <?php $prodArray = $value->product;
                    echo explode(',',$prodArray)  ?>
                </td>
         </tr>
  <?php } ?>
```

So, how can i explode and fetch the data in codeigniter

Comment: are you facing any error?

Comment: `echo explode(',',$prodArray) ` this line is just wrong. You can't echo an array like this.

Comment: Please, post a $res array format example.

Comment: You can convert an array to a string: `$arrStr = print_r(explode(',',$prodArray), true); echo $arrStr;`

Answer (score 1):

VIEW FILE

```
   <table>
    <th>
    <td>S. NO</td>
    <td>Product Name</td>
    </th>
    <tbody>
    <?php 
    $no = 1;
    foreach($products as $product){
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $no;?></td>
    <td><?php echo $product->product_name;?></td> //update with your column name
    </tr>
    <?php   
    $no++;}
    ?>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

MODEL FILE

```
public function get_products()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('products_table'); //update with your table name
    return $this->db->get()->result_object(); // sucess result or handle exceptiom here
}
```

CONTROLLER FILE

```
public function product()
{
    $this->load->model('product'); // can be loaded in the parent::__construct(); at the begining of the controller
    $this->products = $this->product->get_products();
    $this->load->view('products_view');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach ($res as $key => $value) {
    $prodArray = $value->product;
    if($prodArray){ foreach($prodArray as $product) {
 ?>
     <tr class="border-bottom">
            <td>
                <?php echo $product; ?>
            </td>
     </tr>
<?php } } } ?>
```